# Detect if the user is logged out of Facebook

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-oauth

I have a [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) web application that uses Facebook [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) 2.0 to register/login/logout users using [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth).

I enabled the deprecation of offline access on my Facebook application so now I receive tokens that expire after ~two months, or when the user changes her password, or when she removes the application, **BUT not when she logs out of Facebook**

My application is embedded in an iframe into multiple websites and is used to push updates to the user's Facebook timeline.

Say I have my application installed on site A and site B. If the user X logs in my application on A, he is logged into my application on B as well because the iframe preserves the session.

**Problem**

If the user X logs out of Facebook, anyone else using the same computer on sites that have my application installed is going to push updates on behalf of X.

**Is there a way to determine if X is still logged into Facebook before pushing an update?**

In other words, I need something similar to Facebook's JavaScript SDK [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) but on the server side in **Node.js**. The best thing would be a [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) call, but I can't find an appropriate [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) for it.

**IMPERFECT SOLUTION:**

In the end, I went with @NitzanTomer's solution described in the comments. I used the JavaScript [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) and its `FB.getLoginStatus` method to check if the current user of my application is still logged in on Facebook. This is far from ideal: it works in my case because I'm running JavaScript code in an iframe, thus being relatively protected from attacks by the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: The access token only gets invalidated in certain cases, such as removal of the app, or using the js sdk *FB.logout* method. Why do you care if the access token is still valid or not? Also, a valid access token does not mean "user is online".

Comment: @NitzanTomer The problem is this: if a user uses my app, then logs out of fb and leaves the computer, then, another user come in, logs in on his facebook and stumbles upon my app, From the point of view of my app the initial user is still logged in, so every action that the second user does is published by on the first user's facebook account. This is correct as the initial user didn't logout from my app, but why doesn't facebook complain when i try to publish on part of a logged out user.

Comment: I see. Are you talking about a canvas app inside facebook?

Comment: @NitzanTomer It's a widget that people put into their site

Comment: Ok, you're going to have to elaborate on your situation more in order to get help. How are you authenticating the users with facebook? Is it a server-side flow or client-side? Please describe exactly how the users engage with your app.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Sure! I'm building a widget that website owners paste into their site. This embeds an iframe into their page so i can preserve the session from my domain. Auth is done with Facebook OAuth 2.0 using a server-side flow, implemented in node.js. Users click buttons in the widget which publishes actions on their facebook profile.

Comment: How can you use the server side flow within a widget iframe? How do you send the user for fb authentication using the oauth dialog?

Comment: @NitzanTomer i have updated the question to be easier to understand. The -1 hurts :(

Comment: I don't completely get what you're trying to do, but if you're loading iframes then just load the js sdk in those iframes and have access to the *FB.getLoginStatus*. Also, I'm sorry about the -1, but I had nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can you use FB.getLoginStatus to check whether the user is connected to Facebook or not:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: I'm not using the js sdk. Is there a REST API call with similar functinality?

Comment: You can use getLoginStatusUrl. Two sources:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginStatusUrl/
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7538684/how-do-i-use-facebook-getloginstatusurl

Comment: I'm building my app in node.js so i don't have access to php sdk:(

Comment: Facebook are in the process of deprecating the REST API. I would advise against building a new app using that interface.

Comment: I have updated the question title and description. Hope it's clearer

Answer (score 0):

getLoginStaus function is not there in facebook-node-sdk by amachang but what you can use is the getLoginStatusUrl function: [facebook-node-sdk](https://github.com/amachang/facebook-node-sdk/blob/master/lib/basefacebook.js#L398)

The user is logged in if returned value is the url you assign to ok_session property. You cannot be sure of the permissions granted to your app though